# How can I fix my x-axis to show all the years that is within my dataset on my graph as well as take away the .0 .5 at the end of each year label?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph, x-axis

I'm having issues on being able to show all the years on my graph that are represented in my dataset such as 2008,2009,2010,2011,2013,2014,2015,2016,and 2017.

It is only using the years 2010 2012 2015 along with strange .0 .5 at the end of them. How do I fix this?

Here is my code so far.

```
co2emissionsdata %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = `CO2EmissionsPerCapita(tonne)`, color= State)) +
  geom_line() +
```

I tried using `scale_x_continuous()` but nothing happened as I am very new so I'm not sure if I was using the function correctly, via filling in the correct things for my graph or there is another method that will fix this issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try with `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2008:2017)` to get a break for each year. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`.

Comment: Oh thank you!!! I'll try that and see how I go, and shoot I thought I added a picture of my graph but I guess it didn't save it properly.

Comment: You can always [edit] your question if you need to add anything Sara.

Comment: It worked, wow that was an easy fix haha, thank you so much for your help!!